# Equivalent norms on space of ultra-distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

In the third volume of the book "Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications" by Lions and Magenes it is stated (Remark 1.2., page 16) that on the space $
\mathcal D _{M_k}(\Omega , \mathcal K , L)$
the norms
$$
\|\varphi\|_{\infty,\infty} := \sup_{x \in \mathcal K, \alpha \in \mathbb N ^d} \frac{|\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|}{L^kM_k},\quad \|\varphi\|_{\infty,2} := \sup_{\alpha \in \mathbb N ^d} \frac{\|\partial^\alpha \varphi\|_{L^2(\mathcal K)}}{L^kM_k},\quad \|\varphi\|_{2,2} := \sqrt{ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\|\partial^\alpha \varphi\|_{L^2(\mathcal K)}}{L^{2k}M_k^2}}
$$
are equivalent. This I fail to convince myself and I would like to understand it in the simplest case that matches their framework:
$$
\Omega = \mathbb R,\quad \mathcal K = [0,1],\quad L = 1,\quad M_k = (k!)^2
$$
which means that the set $V := \mathcal D _{M_k}(\Omega , \mathcal K , L)$ is made of those $\varphi \in C^\infty[0,1]$ such that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb N,\quad \varphi^{(k)}(0) = \varphi^{(k)}(1) = 0
$$
and
$$
\sup_{k \in \mathbb N} \frac{\| \varphi^{(k)}\|_{L^\infty(0,1)}}{(k!)^2} < \infty.
$$
It is trivial that
$$
\| \cdot \|_{\infty , 2} \lesssim \| \cdot \|_{\infty , \infty},\quad \| \cdot \|_{\infty , 2} \lesssim \| \cdot \|_{2,2}
$$
but for instance I cannot see why
$$
\| \cdot \|_{\infty , \infty} \lesssim \| \cdot \|_{\infty , 2}.
$$
Of course I should use the Poincaré inequality
$$
\exists C_P > 0,\quad \forall u \in H^1_0(0,1),\quad \|u\|_{L^\infty(0,1)} \leq C_P \|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}
$$
but it only gives me that for all $\varphi \in V$, $x \in [0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb N$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{|\varphi^{(k)}(x)| }{(k!)^2} &\leq C_P\frac{\|\varphi^{(k+1)}\|_{L^2(0,1)} }{(k!)^2} \\
&= C_P \frac{((k+1)!)^2}{(k!)^2} \frac{\|\varphi^{(k+1)}\|_{L^2(0,1)} }{((k+1)!)^2} \\
&= C_P (k+1)^2 \frac{\|\varphi^{(k+1)}\|_{L^2(0,1)} }{((k+1)!)^2} 
\end{align*}
$$
Any reference, hint or counter-exampe would be appreciated.

Comment: There's something off, I think: Fix $f$ smooth in $\Omega$ with support in $K$, and *define* $M_k:=\| f^{(k)}\|_{L^2}$, $L=1$. Then $\| f\|_{\infty,2}=1$, but $\| f\|_{2,2}=\infty$, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are answering the question when $(M_k)$ is arbitrary (what I was unable to do!).

Comment: @Jose27 Now the thing is that the authors (Lions and Magenes) take a sequence $(M_k)$ with more properties and it could be that your sequence $(M_k)$ does not match this framework. I will update accordingly.

Comment: What I do think is true is, for instance, that the $\infty,\infty$ and $2, 2$ norms, with some values of $L$ are controlled by the $\infty, 2$ norm with some other value $L'$. Maybe this is enough? My guess is $K$ and $L$ are in some inductive limit business, so this might be fine.